# StringMatchQ with Alternatives

Tags: functions, pattern-matching, string-manipulation, expression-test

Why when trying to find whether one (out of several) patterns matches an expression - using `StringMatchQ` - all of them seem to be ignored and no matches are found?
In this simple example I try to find out whether or not the 4-letter-long string `"abcd"` starts with an "a"

```
StringMatchQ[
  StartOfString ~~ "a" ~~ _ ~~ _ ~~ _]["abcd"]
```

> True

However, when I try to test whether it starts with either an "a" or, say, a "b",

```
StringMatchQ[
      StartOfString ~~ "a" ~~ _ ~~ _ ~~ _|StartOfString ~~ "b" ~~ _ ~~ _ ~~ _]["abcd"]
```

> False

Shouldn't it be true since the first of the two patterns is a match? Isn't this used to specify that either one pattern or the other is the pattern to be matched?

Comment: For that specific example `StringMatchQ["a*" | "b*"]["abcd"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the patterns with parantheses:

```
StringMatchQ[(StartOfString ~~ "a" ~~ _ ~~ _ ~~ _) | 
  (StartOfString ~~ "b" ~~ _ ~~ _ ~~ _)]["abcd"]
```

> True

Alternatively, use the input form of `Alternatives`:

```
StringMatchQ[Alternatives[StartOfString ~~ "a" ~~ _ ~~ _ ~~ _, 
   StartOfString ~~ "b" ~~ _ ~~ _ ~~ _]]["abcd"]
```

> True