# Alternatives not working with Sequence[]?

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation, filtering, sequence

In the following piece of code I've specified two possibilities to match via `Alternatives`, but only one of them seems to be considered:

```
list= {{"ABC:123", "CDE:456", "LMN:789"}, {"CDE:456", "LMN:789"}}
Cases[list, {OrderlessPatternSequence[_?(StringMatchQ["LMN:" ~~ __]),
      _?(StringMatchQ["CDE:" ~~ __]), (_?(StringMatchQ["ABC:" ~~ __])) | (Sequence[])]}]
```

returns:

> {{"ABC:123", "CDE:456", "LMN:789"}}

however I would expect the sublist

> {"CDE:456", "LMN:789"}

to also be returned, since one of the third elements is allowed to be an empty `Sequence`. In fact:

```
list= {{"ABC:123", "CDE:456", "LMN:789"}, {"CDE:456", "LMN:789"}}
Cases[list, {OrderlessPatternSequence[_?(StringMatchQ["LMN:" ~~ __]),
      _?(StringMatchQ["CDE:" ~~ __]), Sequence[]]}]
```

returns:

```
{{"CDE:456", "LMN:789"}}
```

I've also checked the order in which the alternative patterns are specified doesn´t make a difference and the same single sublist is returned.

I thought it might be an issue with the high precedence of `?`, but wrapping everything in parenthesis doesn't solve it (as does [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/213642/stringmatchq-with-alternatives)). I've also seen [similar issues](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/235562/stringmatchq-fails-using-alternatives-with-complex-pattern) arising when the patterns involved have a coincident name (not the case here). What's going on?

Comment: replace `(Sequence[])` with `___`?

Comment: I already had tried that and indeed works for me, but I wanted to be more specific and specify that either one extra element in the list that matches `(_?(StringMatchQ["ABC:" ~~ __]))`should be allowed, or none at all. `___` would include there any type of extra element right? Also, just out of curiosity even if it were as specific, why does `(Sequence[])`works alone but cannot be specified as part of `Alternatives`...?

Comment: `Sequence[]`will just get evaluated and disappear (you can evaluate the pattern in a separate cell to see this): You need to use `PatternSequence[]` instead. As for limiting the number of elements matched by `___`: The fullform `BlankNullSequence` has an additional argument to specify the minimum/maximum number of elements to match.

Comment: @LukasLang thanks for that!, very informative. If you post it as an answer I’d accept it. I've also tried to reformulate the title of the question to better reflect the issue